# How to programmatically exit fullscreen mode in WebView?

Tags: c#, webview, uwp

So let's say I opened html5 video in fullscreen mode (after which WebView raised `ContainsFullScreenElementChanged` and it's `ContainsFullScreenElement` is true now). How can I programmatically exit it?

I'm hooking up to `SystemNavigationManager.GetForCurrentView().BackRequested` and want to exit from full screen mode if it's present, and call WebView.GoBack() if it's not.

WebView doesn't have any related method and ApplicationView class isn't helping either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so after searching some more I found a solution.

HTML5 has [fullscreen api](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn265028%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which can be used for requiring fullscreen or exiting it. You can run it by using `InvokeScriptAsync` method of the WebView. In my particular case I ended up with code similar to this:

```
string[] args = {
    @"if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
      }
      else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
        document.msExitFullscreen();
      }"
};

await CurrentWebView.InvokeScriptAsync("eval", args);
```

First clause is actually what works for me, but I left second one just in case.

Oh btw, if you calling `InvokeScriptAsync` in `BackRequested` handler as I do, you might want to set `BackRequestedEventArgs.Handled` to true **before** you call it, since this is an asynchronous method and the event will be passed further to other subscribers unhandled, which might cause undesirable behaviour.

**EDIT:** Seems like this script doesn't work in the Anniversary Update (build 14393). However, if you add one more check with webkit prefix, it will work. Something like this (or you can just leave a single check with webkit prefix):

```
string[] args = {
    @"if (document.exitFullscreen) {
        document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
        document.msExitFullscreen();
    } else if(document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
        document.webkitExitFullscreen();
    }"
};
```